# How do you find a phrase with Lucene?

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, morelikethis

I hope the way I worded my question is correct, though I could be mistaken.  Basically, I have an index with term vectors, positions, and offsets, and I want to be able to do the following: when I see the word "do", check to see if the next word is "you".  If so, treat those two words as one phrase for the purposes of scoring.  I'm doing this to avoid splitting up words that are commonly used together anyway.  Instead of my list of words sorted by score looking like this,

```
do 
want
you
come
to
```

I'd like to see something more like this

```
do you
want
come
to
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like you are trying to reinvent the wheel.  What is this meant to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to de-clutter my results by combining common phrases

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be index both by word and by phrase, so your scoring list would be:

```
do you
want
come
to
do
you
```

If you then applied a boost to your phrases during indexing, you would be closer to your goal. But that depends on whether matching phrases should always rank higher than their individual words.

It might also be worth looking at [Boosting Lucene Terms When Building the Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880396/boosting-lucene-terms-when-building-the-index).

Comment: I suppose that is possible, but isn't having position vectors supposed to accomplish this without redundancies?